# Trouble comparing TimeInterval to Integer

Tags: iphone, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to compare the timeInterval to an integer value, so I try and convert the timeInterval to an integer and compare. But I'm getting an error 'Cannot convert to a pointer type':

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
int intSecondsElapsed = [timeInterval intValue]; // Error here !!!!

if ([counterInt != intSecondsElapsed])
{
    // Do something here...
}
```

How would go about doing this ?

**EDIT: Include more detail relating to Execute error.**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    startTime = [NSDate date];
    [formatter release];


if ([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone 4"]||[deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"])
    {
        int intSecondsElapsed = (int)[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
        if (counterInt != intSecondsElapsed)
        {
            counterInt = intSecondsElapsed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code too. `if !([counterInt == intSecondElapsed])` shouldn't have square brackets around it. Also, you could simplify the statement like this: `if (counterInt != intSecondsElapsed)`

Comment: Thanks, I realised that when compiling. I've edited my question to reflect your change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is defined as double so if you want to convert it to int you can make simple type cast

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
int intSecondsElapsed = (int)timeInterval;
```

or simply

```
int intSecondsElapsed = (int)[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

**Edit:** If you initialize and use your `startTime` variable in different functions you need to retain it then. `[NSDate date]` returns autoreleased object so it becomes invalid outside the scope it was created. To make things easier declare a property with retain attribute for `startTime` and create it using

```
self.startTime = [NSDate date];
```

And don't forget to release it in your class dealloc method.

Comment: Vladimir, your code change compiled cleanly but I'm getting an 'EXE_BAD_ACCESS" while executing on line 'int intSecondsElapsed = (int)[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];'

Answer (score 2):

What Vladimir said is exactly right, I just wanted to add that the reason that you were seeing the error "Cannot convert to a pointer type" is because you tried to send the message `intValue` to `timeInterval`, which you can only do if what you're sending the message to is a pointer to an object that will respond to it. The compiler tried to treat `timeInterval` as a pointer, but failed.